# IdentityServer4 Redirect to different client after login

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, multi-tenant, blazor-webassembly

I'm starting a new project and using IS4 for authentication.
The application will have a single client and API, that that is distributed across multiple regions.
The user will have a region assigned to their profile, so that they can be redirected to their regional URL(probably defined by subdomain) after they login, how can this be achieved?

e.g. User navigates to https://example.com and is requested to login.
In the login process the user has a region defined e.g. United-Kingdom.
The user is authenticated and now I need to redirect them to their Client that will be hosted on https://uk.example.com

Comment: why not to leave that redirect role to the example.com itself? that could be easier and without breaking the protocol. if such approach is acceptable, I can explain in details

Comment: I did think of that, but wasn't sure if the cookie would then still be valid?

Comment: something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0)?

Comment: Looks promising, I will have a look tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Do you have an example of this maybe? Because it could also be that the user goes directly to uk.example.com and then is redirected to login. but i guess my biggest question is how do I do the redirect after initial login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the OIdC spec, Identity provider has to redirect user after interactive sign in to the valid URL, provided with the authorization request. However I see at least two options to solve the requirements without any changes on Identity side.

Both require some job on the master site, http://example.com
You can tweak the `OnTicketReceived` handling so that it redirects to a local site, based on some claim instead of the path originally requested by the user.
That could look like:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
  options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
  {
    OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
    {
      var identity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
      var locale = identity?.Claims.
        FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Locale)?.Value??"en-GB";
      switch (locale)
      {
        case "ru-RU":
          ctx.ReturnUri = "http://ru.example.com"; 
          //or just example.ru, doesn't matter
          break;
        default:
          ctx.ReturnUri = "http://uk.example.com"; 
          break;
      }
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }
}
```

And here we face two alternatives:

- To register each local site as an individual OIdC client, so that they perform as an ordinary SSO solution where the satellite sites could be even hosted separately.
- Or to share the auth cookie among all the local sites as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-5.0). In this case you have to control them all.